# Is PlayFramework v 1.x production-safe?

Tags: java, playframework

I am planning to start work on a new system, and this time rather than my beloved Spring, I am willing to use PlayFramework. I started playing with the 1.x release, got a few books, and docs, but then realized that v 2.x is a complete rewrite, which is backwards incompatible.

So I am in front of a dilemma. Keep with 1.x (which i like a lot, because it has the very essentials that I need), move to 2.x (although it seems to look more like Spring than PF 1.x), or get back to Spring.

How production-stable is version 1.x? I saw already that there are many plugins/modules which work only with 2.x, but this should not be a big deal, as long as v 1.x keeps being supported, and bugs being fixed. Or is it essentially dead?

Answer (score 2):

[This short FAQ](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1494-add-faqs-about-future-play-1x-plans) is 9 months old, but it shows the position of the developers of Play on that question, anyway. Probably, not much changed from April, 2012. In short, they say that they are going to provide bug fixes for 1.2.x branch and say about their 1.x codebase as of

> a stable codebase and ideal for projects that want stability and backward compatibility in the future.

So, you are not going to be in danger if you stay on 1.2.x if you will follow the security updates of this branch.